# onclick function not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in reactjs, practicing some codes but getting some error on onclick function(Error is function is not executing), can anyone help to find out the error I have done, here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Hello extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      time: Date.now()
    };

    this.changeTime = this.changeTime.bind(this);
  }

  changeTime() {

    alert('hi');
    this.setState({
      time: Date.now()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
          <h3>Current Time : {this.state.time}</h3>
          <br />
          <button onlcick={this.changeTime}>Change Time </button>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `<button onClick={this.changeTime}>Change Time </button>`

not `<button onlcick={this.changeTime}>Change Time </button>`